# Android Post Request with oauth 1.0A

Tags: java, android, http, magento, post

I have recently started developing an `Android` application for my companies `Magento` 2 store.

Magento has a built in `REST API` to retrieve data and it uses `OAuth 1.0a`.

I am quite familiar with developing for android and sending HTTP requests but I have never sent one using this type of authorisation. From Magento i have generated the necessary access tokens to connect to the api and have tested them using Postman and they work correctly. The tokens i have are:

- Consumer Key
- Consumer Secret
- Access Token
- Access Token Secret

I have searched around quite a bit but cannot find a solution, how do i add these to the header of a post request in `Java, Android`?

Thanks.

From the Magento Dev Docs:
`Magento REST API uses 3-legged OAuth 1.0a protocol to authenticate the application to access the Magento service.`